# $.ajax not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery

I have used `$.post` before, now trying `$.ajax`, here is the code. I don't know why it aint working.

I don't to know how to debug this thing as well, whenever I run this. I get error alert box

```
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Handler1.ashx',
        data: { formula: "formulaId" },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('error');
        },
        success: function (result) {
            alert('success');
        }
    });
```

Handler1.ashx in the same folder

```
namespace RegistrationHTML.HTML
{
    public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("hi");
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("Hello World");

            Console.Out.WriteLine("hi");
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried to alert the error?

Comment: or debug it in a browser other than IE and use `console(result)` and look into js console (ff firebug/ opera dragonfly / chrome inspector)

Comment: Use FF and Firebug. It will give you details about your error.

Comment: In additional to the comments above - not only console, but also "network" tab

Comment: @ahren how to alert the error ??

Comment: instead of `alert('error')`, try `alert(result)`

Comment: Firebug shows error here
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );

Comment: The full `success`/`error` callbacks can be found in [the jQuery ajax  source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/0344a390b7673e2f014dc120a4cc5d3492731369/src/ajax.js#L560).

Answer (score 1):

Try specify the `dataType`:

```
$.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Handler1.ashx',
        data: { formula: "formulaId" },
        dataType: 'html', // or 'text' 
        error: function (result) {
            alert('error');
        },
        success: function (result) {
            alert('success');
        }
    });
```